# AWS ALB Truncating HTTP response

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-elb

I have an ALB with a target group and ECS cluster running PHP API.

I am trying to query the API for a CSV response but I am getting truncated results if the Request is coming through the ALB.

When I SSH into the EC2 instance running the cluster and try to run curl manually (going through the load balancer) the response gets truncated:

```
curl -sSL -D - 'https://my.domain.com/api/export?token=foobar&start_date=01-01-2015&end_date=01-01-2019' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -o /dev/null
```

I am getting these headers:

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Wed, 21 Nov 2018 20:25:27 GMT
content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
content-length: 173019
server: nginx
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-description: File Transfer
content-disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv
cache-control: private, must-revalidate
etag: "b90d0da7b482da96e1a478d59eedd0d16552fbfd"
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains; preload
content-security-policy-report-only: default-src 'self';
x-frame-options: DENY
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
referrer-policy: origin

curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)
```

If I try to run the same curl against the container (running locally - not through ALB)

```
curl -sSL -D - 'http://localhost:32776/api/export?token=foobar&start_date=01-01-2015&end_date=01-01-2019' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -o /dev/null
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 173019
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Description: File Transfer
content-disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Date: Wed, 21 Nov 2018 20:36:55 GMT
ETag: "b90d0da7b482da96e1a478d59eedd0d16552fbfd"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains; preload
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'self;
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: origin
```

When I compare them, there is a difference in the HTTP version. I tried switching to HTTP1 in ALB but still getting the same (or similar) issue: `curl: (18) transfer closed with 130451 bytes remaining to read`.

Another difference is the `Keep-Alive` option. I am not sure if this is an attribute I can enable on the ALB.

When I try to return a different response (complex web page/really long) the response goes through ALB without a problem (not truncated). According to the error message when ALB has `HTTP/1.1` enabled the Response is truncated every time after 42568 bytes.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

If I leave out the `Content-Type` header in the response, it doesn't get truncated.

```
return new Response($content, Response::HTTP_OK, [
    # Works without this:
    # 'Content-Type' => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
    'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
    'Content-Disposition' => "attachment;filename=export.csv",
    'Content-Length' => strlen($content),  
]);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Changing the response `Content-Type` to be `text/html` returns the response properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some joyful debugging, I found this in the Nginx logs from the container:

```
nginx stderr | 2018/11/22 01:03:59 [warn] 39#39: *65 an upstream response is 
buffered to a temporary file /var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi/4/01/0000000014 while reading 
upstream, client: 10.1.1.163, server: _, request: "GET /api/export?
token=foobar&start_date=01-01-2015&end_date=01-01-2019 HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "my.domain.com"
```

Which can basically be solved by baking in these two lines into my nginx config:

```
client_body_temp_path /tmp 1 2;
fastcgi_temp_path /tmp 1 2;
```

The question why was this happening only for `csv` output will remain a mystery.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should enable keep-alive on your EC2 instances.

> You can enable HTTP keep-alive in the web server settings for your EC2
>   instances.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout

Also double check that the Content-Length header is accurate. An incorrect size here will result in the error you are seeing.

Comment: Where exactly would that be? Load Balancer has the timeout set to `120 seconds`. Do you mean the ECS EC2 instances that are running the cluster? The web server in the container has the `Keep-Alive` option enabled as well.

Comment: Sorry, missed the ECS bit. Should be fine if you've got keep-alive set on your web server. Not sure why it's getting stripped out. Do you have anything else like a firewall or something that could be intercepting HTTP?

Comment: I don't believe so, there is an update in my original question, maybe that helps?